# How can I write a file on a read-only

Tags: mount, read-only

I am accessing a device via SSH. I would like to change a file on the `www` directory, but when attempting to do this it says `Read-only file system`.

`mount` gives me some info, but I cannot see any references to `www`, why `www` is RO or how `www` is mounted:

```
admin@(none):/# mount
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)
/dev/root on / type squashfs (ro,relatime)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=127752k,nr_inodes=31938,mode=755)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,mode=600)
/dev/mtdblock4 on /jffs type jffs2 (rw,noatime)
usbfs on /proc/bus/usb type usbfs (rw,relatime)
```

It has nothing to do, but I have permissions to write the file:

```
drwxr-xr-x   14 admin root          5999 May 27 05:17 www
```

What could I do?

---

```
admin@(none):/# ls -l /
drwxr-xr-x    2 admin root             3 May 27 05:17 asus_jffs
drwxr-xr-x    2 admin root           667 May 27 05:12 bin
drwxr-xr-x    2 admin root             3 May 27 05:17 cifs1
drwxr-xr-x    2 admin root             3 May 27 05:17 cifs2
drwxr-xr-x    5 admin root          1580 Nov  8 18:46 dev
lrwxrwxrwx    1 admin root             7 May 27 05:17 etc -> tmp/etc
lrwxrwxrwx    1 admin root             8 May 27 05:17 home -> tmp/home
drwxr-xr-x    5 admin root             0 Nov  8 20:19 jffs
drwxr-xr-x    3 admin root           402 May 27 05:17 lib
lrwxrwxrwx    1 admin root             9 May 27 05:17 media -> tmp/media
drwxr-xr-x    2 admin root             3 May 27 05:17 mmc
lrwxrwxrwx    1 admin root             7 May 27 05:17 mnt -> tmp/mnt
lrwxrwxrwx    1 admin root             7 May 27 05:17 opt -> tmp/opt
dr-xr-xr-x   97 admin root             0 Jan  1  1970 proc
drwxr-xr-x    7 admin root           766 May 27 05:17 rom
lrwxrwxrwx    1 admin root            13 May 27 05:17 root -> tmp/home/root
drwxr-xr-x    2 admin root          2566 May 27 05:17 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   11 admin root             0 Jan  1  1970 sys
drwxr-xr-x    2 admin root             3 May 27 05:17 sysroot
drwxrwxrwx   12 admin root           880 Nov  8 20:19 tmp
drwxr-xr-x    8 admin root           139 May 27 05:17 usr
lrwxrwxrwx    1 admin root             7 May 27 05:17 var -> tmp/var
drwxr-xr-x   14 admin root          5999 May 27 05:17 www
```

Comment: According t6o your output '/dev/root' is RO. Can you aqdd the output of `ls -l /' to show us if there is a direct link of `/www` on `/`? (If so it would ofc be RO). Please also add if this is a router or not (many of those have root RO on flash, so you would want to add data in another place).

Comment: Thanks. No link as you can see in the edit. It is a router.

Comment: `www` seems re gular directory on .`/`. And `/` is mounted RO. Thus you either need to make / RW, or (more likely) tell your webserver to use another directory, e.g. on a mounted USB pendrive or on /tmp/www' (the latter probably being cleaned every reboot, but useful for testing)

Comment: Where do you see / is RO? (/dev/root?) Well, I would prefer making / (or just www) RW if there is a way to do it

Comment: 1) Yes, from your output: `/dev/root on / type squashfs (ro,relatime)`.  
2) If / is RO then /something on the same filesystem is also going to be RO. And it is likely RO since on a router / is probably on RO flash.. Notice from your output how every filesystem which needs writing seems to be suymlinked to /tmp/. And look at your post to see `tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,relatime)` (RW, READ-WRITE, tempfs).

Comment: Very illustrative. It seems that if it is in the RO flash there is nothing I can (easily) do. So maybe a /tmp/www redirection would be the solution as you said.

Comment: Another possible thing.. is your host has got some critical error. When this happens, often the system goes into full read-only mode (ie. the whole file system - and even if you are root you can't do anything. Its purely read only to avoid further damage). The usual fix is rebooting the system (preferably after you can find out what caused the FS to lock up).

Comment: It doesn't seem the case, but I will take it into consideration